# trying to place svg on top of img

Tags: html, css, svg

I modified my previous code, and now the question is as follows:
I am trying to place an svg on top of an img.
I am able to place in the upper left corner only, with top:0; and left:0;
when I increase these values the svg goes under the container.

```css
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

.video-container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.video-container svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class = "video-container">
          <img class = "video" src="./images/play-video.svg" alt="play-video" />

          <svg width="190" height="63">
            <g>
              <rect x="0" y="0" width="190" height="63" fill="blue"/>
              <text x="50%" y="50%"  fill="white" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Play Video</text>
            </g>
          </svg>
      </div>
```

Comment: You have to specify a unit. Like `top: 1px`. Not just `top: 1`.

Comment: Try setting the img to `relative` and the svg to `absolute`. If that doesn't work, then wrap the img and the svg in separate divs and then set those divs to `relative` and `absolute.`

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: thanks @agrm, it works!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify a unit for `top`. Only `0` don't need a unit.

```css
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

.video-container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.video-container svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "video-container">
          <img class = "video" src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" alt="play-video" />

          <svg width="190" height="60">
            <g>
              <rect x="0" y="0" width="190" height="63" fill="blue"/>
              <text x="50%" y="50%"  fill="white" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Play Video</text>
            </g>
          </svg>
      </div>
```

Comment: This is great, and it works. However, to allign better to left or right, please use right: 1rem; instead of px as it will match more relatively to corners

Answer (score 0):

```
      <div class="description-container">
        <div class = "what-is">
          What is Overpass
        </div >
        <p class="details">
          Overpass connects phone talent from around the world with
          businesses looking to build remote customer engagement teams to
          increase sales, generate leads and so much more.
       </p>
      </div>

      <div class = "video-container">
          <img class = "video" src="./images/play-video.svg" alt="play-video" />

          <svg width="190" height="63">
            <g>
              <rect x="0" y="0" rx="5" ry="5" width="190px" height="63px" fill="#0092FF"/>
              <text x="50%" y="50%"  fill="white" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Play Video</text>
            </g>
          </svg>
      </div>
    </section>
```

```
/* ***** company info container ******* */
.overpass-info-container {
  background-color: #0092FF;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.description-container {
  margin-top: 155px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.what-is {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 72px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  font-weight: 330;
  font-family: Proxima Nova;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 1;
}


.video-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 142px;
  }

.video-container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.video-container svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  left: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #00000029;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```